# Query optimization with a large number of records

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, group-by

I have a few tables with millions of records in each. One of table has a leads data (with click_id field from clicks table). Second (clicks) has click_id as a primary key and has ad_id field (advertise label). It looks like:

### X_leads

id
lead_id
lead_click_id
another_fields

### X_click

click_id
ad_id
another_fields

I need to get data with count of leads and with ad_id label I need.
I have a query like:

`SELECT C.ad_id AS lead_ad_id, COUNT(DISTINCT L.lead_id) AS leads
 FROM X_leads AS L 
 INNER JOIN X_click AS C ON L.lead_click_id=C.click_id
 WHERE (C.shop_id=223) AND (L.owner_id=223) 
 AND (L.lead_active=1) AND (L.lead_invalid=0)
 AND (C.ad_id IN (11, 180, 181, ... {it can be hundred of ids}...))
 GROUP BY L.lead_ad_id`

Today, one query can working 10 seconds or more. 
I tried to optimize it myself, but without any result.
Explain result:
[image]
[image]
How I can to optimize this query?
THanks

Comment: By providing proper DDLs and an EXPLAIN

Comment: What's the large `IN` clause for? Can it be replaced with a `JOIN`? There are columns in your query that aren't in your schema. Provide full schema, including indexes.

Comment: IN have an IDS of advertisment labels. User can select it clicking on checkboxes. (it can be 1 or 200)

Comment: @MarcusAdams as I said IN has a IDS of advertisment labels, that can select user in form. We cant replace it with JOIN. ad_id column in X_click table.
I cant show full schema - it has a lot of tables.

Answer (score 0):

Use explain_plan and avoid full table scans, to avoid it force indexes with the fields you use  in where conditions.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html